# Explain Excel logic X*(Y<0.2)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, ms-office, excel-2007

Can you tell me how this expression is executing?

`X * (Y < 0.2)`

I understand it like if `Y < 0.2` then `X` should be multiplied by `Y`. But what will be if `Y < 0.2` is not true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TRUE/FALSE when used in math returns their Boolean Value of 1/0 respectively.

In this instance when the Y< 0.2 then the expression in the `()` will be 1 and it will return the value of x, Because 1 * x is x.

If it is false it will return 0.  because 0 * x is 0

Answer (score 1):

The part in parentheses, (Y < 0.2), evaluates to either `FALSE` (a 0) or `TRUE` (a 1). So if the part in parentheses is false, it would return 0.

```
X   Y   Y < 0.2 x*(y<.2)
3   1   FALSE   0
3   0.1 TRUE    3
```